# Room @Transaction fails to run however individual functions run

Tags: android, android-room

My entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
val userID:String,
val userName:String,
val userRoleName:String,
val adminID:String,
val name:String,
val email:String,
val phoneNumber:String,
val adminType:String,
val batchID:String,
val centerID:String,
val batchName:String,
val centerName:String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

My Dao

```
@Dao
abstract class MDao {

    @Insert
    abstract suspend fun insert(user: User)

    @Query("select userID from user_table")
    abstract suspend fun getuserID():String

    @Query("select adminID from user_table")
    abstract suspend fun getadminID():String

    @Delete
    abstract suspend fun deleteUser(user: User)

    @Query("delete from user_table")
    abstract fun deleteUserTable()


    @Query("select count(*) from user_table")
    abstract suspend fun getUserTableCount() : Int

    @Transaction
    open suspend fun insertUser(user: User){
        deleteUserTable()
        insertUser(user)
    }
}
```

I am using coroutines to use these functions, if I call the delete and insert one by one the code runs smoothly.

```
val dao :MDao = mDatabase(it).getDao()
                            dao.deleteUserTable()
                            dao.insert(user)
```

but if I call the transaction there is an error:

```
val dao :MDao = mDatabase(it).getDao()
                            dao.insertUser(user)
```

error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1042KB
        at kotlinx.coroutines.Job$DefaultImpls.get(Unknown Source:8)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.get(JobSupport.kt:27).....
```

sometimes I also get an error that says that the database is readonly.

Comment: your ```insertUser(user: User)``` function is calling itself which is causing StackOverflowError

Comment: so silly of me.... thanks for pointing it out. Hey if I add a large list into room is there a callback to show the end of transaction? I am very new to room and I do not know how live data works.

Comment: I don't think there is a callback for database transaction. but you can create your own callback and call it after the transaction.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: It is best to ask this as a new question. also include what you tried and where you are stuck

Comment: ok I'll do that thanks